# iOS 7: Change height of UIAlertView

Tags: ios7, uiviewcontroller, height, uialertview, custom-view

I've gone through several posts explaining how to change alert view height but none of worked for me. Here is the scenario:

I am inserting a custom view inside alert view like this:

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"MyView"];
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Submit", nil];                                                                                                           
[alertView setValue: myViewController.view  forKey:@"accessoryView"];              
[alertView show];
```

After adding custom view (i.e. myViewController.view), the size of alert view increased unnecessarily. To set desired size to alert view, I implemented following method:

```
- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    [alertView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 300)];
}
```

Still there was no change in alert view height. Any ideas how can I do that? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved..!! I just changed the height of sub view. Inside `viewDidLoad` method of `MyViewController` I adjusted the size of view.